# Support iOS 3.2 (or 4.0) with XCode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I uploaded an application to AppStore with minimum support of `iOS 3.2`. Then I downloaded `XCode 4.5` with `iOS 6.0 SDK` and I want to release an update for my 3.2 supported app. But as you know, 4.3 can be selected as minimum version in XCode 4.5. But since my project is older, I can select 3.2. I wonder if I build and upload my app with 3.2 selected as seen in the picture, will it support 3.2?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't build and submit an iOS 3.2 compatible app using Xcode 4.5.

Xcode 4.5 cannot build an armv6 binary executable slice, which is required for all Deployment targets below iOS 4.3 (except in the very unusual case where you initially submitted an iOS 3.x armv7-only app).

Comment: "which is required for all Deployment targets below iOS 4.3" but why not simply drop this requirement now? It seems like a stupid reason

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5 not support ios 4.3 and less

Comment: You mean it doesn't support a lower IOS than 4.3, right ?. I understood 4.3 was being supported.

Comment: 4.3 is being supported, he means only less than 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Summmar tab[image: screenshot] and edit as text the desired Deployment target field ( XCode 4.5 )

Comment: But do you think this will work. Because developer.apple.com says : "This release of Xcode doesn’t allow submitting to the App Store apps with iOS Deployment Target set to iOS releases earlier than iOS 4.3. T". But I still could upload versions for 3.2 as I said before.

Comment: I have serious problems supporting a mixed ios5 and ios6 project, why the hell want 3.2?! Those will buy your product who can't upgrade to iOS 5.0 at least? There is only 1 way to know for sure if is working: try it!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode):

> In June 2010 at the World Wide Developers Conference, Apple announced version 4 of Xcode during the Developer Tools State of the Union address. Version 4 of the developer tools consolidates the Xcode editing tools and Interface Builder into a single application, among other enhancements.[13][14] Apple released the final code for Xcode 4.0 on March 9, 2011. The software was made available for free to all registered members of the $99 per year Mac Developer program and the $99 per year iOS Developer program. It was also sold for $4.99 to non-members on the Mac App Store (no longer available). Xcode 4.0 drops support for many older systems, including all PowerPC development as well as SDKs for Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5, and all iOS SDKs older than 4.3. The deployment target can still be set to produce binaries for those older platforms, but for the Mac OS platforms one is then limited to creating x86 and x86_64 binaries.

It says there that starting from Xcode 4.0, Apple removed support for iOS 4.3. The SDK is no longer available. But one can still provide binaries for older platforms.

Comment: But I tried to upload a version built with 3.2 with this way. And in binary details (iTunesConnect), minimum OS version was seen as 3.2. Also It says "deployment target can still be set to produce binaries for those older platforms" in your citation. That's the important part I think. Thanks.

Comment: @ugur Yeah, should've read that through. I will edit that to avoid further confusing. But I think it's best to embrace new features. Anyway, good luck!